# How to minimize memory usage in akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have stream that at some point will group objects to create files.
I think I can squeeze some bytes by serializing the object early in the stream.
But my biggest question is about how to optimize the memory footprint for a stream like this:

```
val sourceOfCustomer = Source.repeat(Customer(name = "test"))
def serializeCustomer(customer: Customer) = customer.toString

sourceOfCustomers
.via(serializeCustomer) // 1KB
.grouped(1000000) // 1GB
.via(processFile) // 1GB
.via(moreProcessing) // 1GB
.via(evenMoreProcessing) // 1GB
.to(fileSink) // 1GB
```

This gives me a memory usage at steady state of **at least 5GB**. Is this correct?

What strategy can I use to only limit it to 1 or 2GB? In principle it should be possible by collapsing the operators.

Note: I know a solution is to make the group smaller but let’s consider the size of the group a constraint of the problem.

Comment: Breakdown each computation input/output into more granular parts.

Comment: Please, provide type of `sourceOfCustomers` and `serializeCustomer` and short description what they are doing. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanKurchenko they can be anything but I updated the question with their description

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, maybe I'm missing something, but I did not find `group` operation in latest Akka Stream documentation, I guess you mean `grouped` operation: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/grouped.html .

If so, then it means that at `.grouped(1000000) // 1GB` you create group of elements in the stream , which can be handled simultaneously, hence one more then one group of 1GB size can present in memory in one moment of time. So in order to limit memory footprint in your stream up to 1GB, you can go with one of two ways:

1) Reduce number of large groups handled simultaneously.
This can be achieved with `throttle` operation: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/throttle.html#throttle
Please, see code snippet for example

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
...

.group(1000000) // 1GB
.throttle(1, 1 minute)
```

2) Reducing large group size

```
val parallelismLevel = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() // or another custom level which represents stream processing parallelism
val baseGroupSize = 1000000 // 1GB
val groupSize =  baseGroupSize / parallelismLevel 

sourceOfCustomers
.via(serializeCustomer) // 1KB
.group(groupSize)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I would not consider this a solution but it is definitely a workaround. I guess you don’t want to sacrifice speed in the solution. Also the size of the file it’s a constrain of the problem.

Comment: @gurghet Sorry, I did not know that file size is constraint.

Comment: @gurghet Well, I don't want sacrifice speed - but from my point of view this is example of `memory-performance` balance problem.  If you want to handle 1G file in memory and you don't want to use more then 1G of memory at all , you will need to handle 1 file at time. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: I don’t want to turn this into a conversation but yes you are right. Just pointing out there are better solutions.